# I need to replace an engine in my heritage

Tags: engine, motorcycle

My 2002 heritage has over 48,000 miles on it and is making a lot of noise so I would like to replace it with a 2003 road king motor. Would it line up and bolt in without any trouble.

Answer (score 1):

It would take a lot of effort to mount a RK motor on a Heritage softtail. The motor on the Heritage softtail is hard mounted to the frame and has a counterbalancer to stop the motor from shaking around in the frame, while the RK is missing the counterbalancer and is rubber mounted to the frame which lets the engine to freely "wobble" in the frame. So you would first have to address these issues then I know that the top mounts would mount up but the lower mounts have completely different spacing so those would have to be modified as well.